# How can I make TUIO fiducials change the background to different images when it enters a target box in processing?

Tags: java, processing, target, tuio

Goodday,
This is a school project that I am currently working on with my group for our coursework and I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time now.

I am trying to get different fiducials to show different images as the background when the fiducial object enters a target box.

This was done using Processing java and reacTIVision.

```
import TUIO.*;
PImage start, img11;
TuioProcessing tuioClient;
TuioObject tobj;


HashMap<Integer, TrackedObject> objs= new HashMap<Integer, TrackedObject>();
ArrayList<Target> targets=new ArrayList<Target>();

void setup(){
  size(1260, 720);

  tuioClient  = new TuioProcessing(this);
  //int id = tobj.getSymbolID();

  start = loadImage("usecasesystem.png");
  img11 = loadImage("rectsmall.png");

  targets.add(new Target(890, 173, 206, 370));
}

void draw(){
  background(255);

  rect(890, 173, 206, 370);
  noFill();

  // have all targets been hit?
  //boolean allHit=true;

  // draw targets; check if hit.
  for (Target t : targets) {
    t.draw();
    if (t.isEmpty()) { 
      //allHit=false;
    }
  }

  // draw tracked objects
  for (TrackedObject o : objs.values()) {
    o.draw();
  } 
  //if (allHit) { 
  //  text("All Targets Hit", 20, 30);
  //}
}

// called when an object is added to the scene
synchronized void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  int id = tobj.getSymbolID();
  TrackedObject o = new TrackedObject(id);
  o.setPos(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));

  o.size=(int)random(50, 100);
  o.fillCol=color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
  objs.put(new Integer(id), o);

  for (Target t : targets) {
    if (t.contains(o.x, o.y)) {
      t.entered(o);// if o is inside any of the targets, notify that o has left
    }
  }
}

// called when an object is removed from the scene
synchronized void removeTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  int id = tobj.getSymbolID();
  TrackedObject o = objs.get(id);
  for (Target t : targets) {
    t.left(o); // if o was in any of the targets, notify that o has left
  }
  objs.remove(id);
}

// called when an object is moved
synchronized void updateTuioObject (TuioObject tobj) {
  TrackedObject o= objs.get(new Integer(tobj.getSymbolID()));
  int oldX=o.x;
  int oldY=o.y;
  o.x=tobj.getScreenX(width);
  o.y=tobj.getScreenY(height);

  // check if o has moved into any of the targets; if so, notify the target
  for (Target t : targets) {
    boolean wasIn = t.contains(oldX, oldY); // was o in the target on the previous go?
    boolean isIn = t.contains(o.x, o.y); // is o in the target now?

    if (isIn) {
      t.moved(o); // o has moved around in the target
      // has object o just moved into the target? 
      if (!wasIn) { // If so, notify the target that o has entered:
        t.entered(o);
      }
    }
    // has object o moved out of the target? 
    if (wasIn && !isIn) { // If so, notify the target that o has left
      t.left(o);
    }
  }
}
```

```
class Target {

  TuioObject tobj;
  HashMap<Integer, TrackedObject> objs= new HashMap<Integer, TrackedObject>();


  /* Rectangular targets.
   have x, y location location & dimensions.
   Maintain a list of TrackedObjects that are currently insite the target.
   Can test whether a location is inside them -- contains(x, y)
   Display colour depends on whether they've been 'hit'.
   */

  int x, y, xSize, ySize, halfXSize, halfYSize, aid;

  color fillCol, hitFillCol, strokeCol;

  // Which TrackedObjects are contained in this target 
  ArrayList<TrackedObject> containedObjects = new ArrayList();


  Target(int xx, int yy, int sx, int sy) {
    x=xx; 
    y=yy; 
    xSize=sx; 
    halfXSize=sx/2;
    ySize=sy;
    halfYSize=sy/2;
    fillCol=color(100, 150);
    hitFillCol=color(200, 0, 0, 150);
    strokeCol=color(0);
    //name=n;
  }

  void draw() {
    pushStyle();
    // change the colour based on whether s trcked object is in target
    //if (containedObjects.size()>0) {
    //  //fill(hitFillCol);
    //  image(start, 0, 0);
    //} 
    //else {
    //  //fill(fillCol);
    //}  
    for (int i = 0; i < containedObjects.size(); i++){
      getidno(tobj); 
    }


    stroke(strokeCol);
    rect(x, y, xSize, ySize);
    noFill();
    //text(name+"     "+ containedObjects.size(), x-xSize/2, y-ySize/2);
    popStyle();
  }

  boolean contains(int ox, int oy) {
    // does this target contain the location (ox, oy)? 
    return (ox>x-halfXSize && ox<x+halfXSize && oy>y-halfYSize && oy<y+halfYSize);
  }

  boolean isEmpty(){
    // target is empty of no TOs are inside.
    return (containedObjects.size()==0);

  }

  void entered(TrackedObject o) {
    containedObjects.add(o);
  }
  void left(TrackedObject o) { 
    containedObjects.remove(o);
  }
  void moved(TrackedObject o) {
  }

  void getidno(TuioObject tobj){
    int id = tobj.getSymbolID();
    TrackedObject o = objs.get(id);
    for (Target t : targets) {
      if (tobj.getSymbolID() == 7){
        image(start, 0, 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
class TrackedObject {
  /* TrackedObjects are things that're displayed
   on screen and created & moved around - e.g. 
   by the movement of TUIO objects
   */

  String text="";

  int x, y;
  float angle=0;
  int size=60;
  int fiducialID;
  color fillCol, strokeCol;

  TrackedObject(int id) {
    //fillCol=color(100);
    //strokeCol=color(200);
    fiducialID=id;
  }

  void draw() {
    /* basic draw method - just draws a circle
     */

    if(fiducialID == 7){
      rect(890, 173, 206, 370);
      pushMatrix();
      translate(x, y);
      image(img11, 0, 0);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }

  void setPos(int xx, int yy){
    x=xx; y=yy; 
  }

  //int getID(int i){
  //  i = tobj.getSymbolID();
  //  return i;
  //}

}
```